# Logger is undefined when using Jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, apollo-client

I have a unit test to assert the link for ApolloLink and my problem is on how to instantiate our logger through Jest. The actual instantiation of my logger will be executed from the caller of `createErrorLink`. Here are the files that I am currently working on.

I need to assert this exported method in **myFile.ts**

```
import { ApolloLink }from '@apollo/client';
import { l } from 'utils/log/log';
import { ErrorResponse, onError } from '@apollo/client/link/error';

export const createErrorLink = (): ApolloLink => {
   return onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }: ErrorResponse) => {
      if (graphQLErrors) {
         l.error("a");   // undefined l (logger)
      }
   })
}
```

Here is my test file
**myFile.test.ts**

```
import * as l from 'utils/log/log';

it ('something', async(done: jest.DoneCallback) => {
// jest.spyOn(l, 'setupLog').mockImplementation(() => {
//    return {
//       error.jest.fn();
//    };
// });

// jest.mock('utils/log/log', () => {
//    return {
//       setupLog: jest.fn(),
//       l: {
//          error.jest.fn();
//       }
//    };
// });

const errorLink = createErrorLink();
const expectedLink = new ApolloLink(() => {
   return new Observable((observer) => { return observer.error(new GraphQLError(mockErrorMessage))});
});

const concatErrorLinks = ApolloLink.from([errorLink, expectedLink]);
executeErrorRequest(concatErrorLinks, done);

});

const executeErrorRequest = (link, done): void => {
   execute(result.errors![0].message).toBe(mockErrorMessage);
   done();
}
```

And lastly, here's my logger content. I cannot change the code in here.
**log.ts:**

```
export function setupLog(w: HTMLElement) {
   l = new Logger({
      ...getSettings()[config.get('LOG_ENV', 'environment')],
      w: (w as any).host || w
   });
}

export let l;
```

Whenever I run my unit test for this particular test case, I always end up receiving "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading "error")".

Tried all sorts of Jest methods i.e. spyon, jest.omck but they were not successful in passing my unit test / instantiating my logger.

UPDATE: Added imports under **myFile.ts**

Comment: Well, your logger is only instantiated by calling the `setupLog` function. As far as I see, that function is not called anywhere. Also jest cannot know that it should call it, unless you do that explicitly, e.g. in a `beforeAll` block of your test - see here: https://jestjs.io/docs/setup-teardown

Comment: @dwytrykus yes it is not called in any of the files mentioned above. but, although im not sure if this is possible, i want to utilize the jest mocking / spyOn to "instantiate" it for me. the code in comment were my attempts but they were not successful.

ill try to dig on the link you gave. thank you for your input.

Comment: If you want to mock your logger (i.e. do not use the real instance in your test), the `jest.mock` statement in your commented code should already do it - but that depends how your logger module is imported in myFile.ts. Can you please show the full myFile.ts?

Comment: @dwytrykus updated my post to show the entire file for `myFile.ts`. with regards to `jest.mock`, that was my initial thought that it should work but for some odd reason, it didn't and i am not so sure anymore what causes the undefined logger.  i am pretty sure (code-wise) that it should work.

Comment: Your `jest.mock` code above contains a mistake: I guess you wanted to write `error: jest.fn();` instead of `error.jest.fn();`. Then it works. There is no need to mock `setupLog`, by the way, since your test and your tested function both never call it. And you don't need to `import * as l from 'utils/log/log';` in your test, since it's not used. The mocking still works without that.